# Rails Active Record CrossTab Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, crosstab

A vehicle has_many services.
services has_many types (0,1,2,3,4).

I need to write a query that shows the mileage reading of when each type of service was last completed for a vehicle.

In my MS ACCESS days this was a simple crosstab (transform) query. Could someone point me in the right direction in the rails environment? Thanks

This is the long hand version of what I'm trying to collate:

```
        @a_last = v.services.maximum(:mileage_closed, :conditions => ["closed = TRUE AND service_type_id > 0"])
        @b_last = v.services.maximum(:mileage_closed, :conditions => ["closed = TRUE AND service_type_id > 1"])
        @c_last = v.services.maximum(:mileage_closed, :conditions => ["closed = TRUE AND service_type_id > 2"])
        @d_last = v.services.maximum(:mileage_closed, :conditions => ["closed = TRUE AND service_type_id > 3"])
        @e_last = v.services.maximum(:mileage_closed, :conditions => ["closed = TRUE AND service_type_id > 4"])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is to iterate through a range and collect your results:

```
mileages = (0..4).collect do |service_type|
  vehicle.services.maximum(:mileage_closed, :conditions => ["CLOSED = TRUE AND SERVICE_TYPE_ID = #{service_type}"]
end
```

I'm guessing you mean to search the service type id with an equals instead of a more than.

This will, however, make 5 sql statements when it is run. You'll probably find this doesn't effect performance too badly. If performance does become an issue, a different approach would be to write an SQL statement to find your results (it'll be grouped by vehicle_id and service_type_id, then run a MAX() on the mileage_closed column) and make that a view in your database. Then you should be able to find these results in a single database round trip.

Comment: Hi AJFaraday, That sounds great thanks, I'll give it a shot. The > is actually deliberate as a 0 service_type may represent 5 service_items, a 1 service_type will represent 10 service_items (which include the 5 service_items in the 0 service_type) 2 = 15 etc, 3 = 20 etc. in a cascading style. This means that if a service_type of 4 was completed, it included all the requirements of 0,1,2 & 3. Thanks

Comment: I'm sure you know your requirements much better than me.

Although if you have types numbered 0 to 4 and look for services with a service_type_id of more than 4... there will never be any results. Just be aware of the difference between < and <=